# How do I uninstall a version of Java from Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: apt, 15.10, java, uninstall

Several month ago I installed a version of java on my machine. Unfortunately, I don't remember how. :(

Now every time I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `update` or `autoremove` I get the following messages:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jdk1.8.0-92
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 272 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-imgproc2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-video2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-flann2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-objdetect2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-features2d2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-core2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-contrib2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-legacy2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-calib3d2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-ml2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 219411 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-92 (1.8.092-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-92.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-92.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-92 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-92
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I just tried upgrading to Ubuntu 16 from the command line and that failed to. So I really need to uninstall the darn thing, but none of the posts I read so far helped me! What should I do to get rid of this Java install (and maybe then install it properly)?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge jdk1.8.0-92`

Comment: @AndroidDev Just tried it. Same result

Comment: 15.10 is outdated and no longer supported, which also means that its repository servers are no longer reachable under the default address. You should upgrade to 16.04 as soon as possible.

Comment: That's what I tried to do and it failed. I can blow away the current install and install 16 from scratch but I am trying my best to avoid it

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Oracle Java 8, just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo update-alternatives --display java
```

To check the setup before uninstalling Java.
Next, remove symlinks

(replace the word (version)with your Java version. DO java -version to get yours. So if your version is 1.8.0-92, you would type **sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0-92/bin/java"**)

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk<version>/bin/java"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk<version>/bin/javac"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk<version>/bin/javaws"
```

verify that the symlinks were removed

```
java -version
javac -version
which javaws
```

The next commands should be enetered with caution  to avoid permanently destroying your system.

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
sudo rm -rf jdk<version>
```

Now edit environmental variables.

```
 sudo vi  /etc/environment
```

Delete lines with JAVA_HOME , JRE_HOME if any

To uninstall OpenJDK (if installed). First check which OpenJDK packages are installed.

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

To remove openjdk:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

Uninstall OpenJDK related packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge icedtea-* openjdk-*
```

Check that all OpenJDK packages have been removed.

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

Thats all.